# How to add image 15 min. before and after sunrise and sunset time in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="sunrise" class="sunrise">06:00</div>
<div id="sunset" class="sunset">20:00</div>
```

I wanna put image1.png on between before after 15 min. sunrise time also sunset time image2.png. (before 15 min. now < sunrise time (image1) < after 15 min. now) (before 15 min. now < sunset time (image2) < after 15 min. now)

```
var doc = document;
clock({
    twentyfour: !!twentyfour,
    padzero: true,
    refresh: 5000,
    success: function (clock) {
        doc.getElementById('time').innerHTML = clock.hour() + ":" + clock.minute();
        document.getElementById('todate').innerHTML = clock.date() + ' ' + translate[current].month[clock.month()] + ' ' + clock.year();
        document.getElementById('today').innerHTML = translate[current].weekday[clock.day()]
    }
});

if (type == "weather") {
    doc.getElementById("sunrise").innerHTML = weather.sunriseTimeFormatted;
    doc.getElementById("sunset").innerHTML = weather.sunsetTimeFormatted;
}
```

How can I write the codes (if-else) (image none-block). Thank you soo much for your helps.

Comment: You seem to be adding the `jailbreak` tag to your questions. Is there a reason for that? I don't think it's pertinent to your question. If not, feel free to [edit] your question and remove it.

Comment: In other words you only want to add an image if the current time is within 15 mins before and after sunrise/sunset?

Comment: Yet another "ask-and-runner"